# c# values not changing when editing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using asp.net MVC4, whenever I try to change values in the edit page I get this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGei7.png)

this is my controller`

```
   public ActionResult Edit( Maison maison)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ms.Update(maison);
            ms.Commit();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(maison);
    }
```

this is my HTML

```
<div class="center">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="site site--main">
            <header class="site__header">
                <h1 class="site__title">Modifier votre annonce</h1>

            </header>
            <div class="site__panel"><span class="site__header-text">Veuillez remplir les champs avec les informations nécessaires, tout les champs avec * sont obligatoire.</span></div>
            <div class="site__main">
                <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Edit","Maisons" , FormMethod.Post)" class="form form--flex form--property-add js-form js-form-property">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="widget js-widget widget--main widget--no-margin widget--no-border widget--collapse">
                        <div class="widget__header">
                            <h2 class="widget__title">Informations de base</h2>

                        </div>
                        <div class="widget__content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">


                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Titre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Titre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Titre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">



                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tutile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label ", @type = "required" })

                                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Tutile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tutile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dimension, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dimension, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dimension, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ville, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })

                                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Ville, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ville, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                                <!-- end of block .form-property__control-->



                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.prix, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.prix, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.prix, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>



                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget js-widget widget--main widget--no-margin widget--no-border widget--collapse">
                        <div class="widget__header">
                            <h2 class="widget__title">Plus d'Information</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget__content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nbrchambre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nbrchambre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nbrchambre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                    <!-- end of block .form-property__control-->
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NbrBathRooms, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NbrBathRooms, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NbrBathRooms, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NbrGarages, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NbrGarages, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NbrGarages, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-group--col-12">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                    <div class="row">
                        <button class="form__submit">Modifier</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried changing button to input and tried using onlick, I'm not sure if the problem is with the method or with html, I'm kinda new to coding if there's more information I need to post please let me know.

Comment: the error message in your picture states clearly that it's not the problem of the code posted here. The problem is you're attaching entities with the same type and primary key to entity framework. I guess the problem is you're using a shared dbcontext somehow

Comment: Yes I think my friend who's helped me, imported a context from another project, considering he knows what he was doing I thought he made it compatible with my project here's the context code 
https://pastebin.com/FHM8ZgWx when I use create or delete in HTML views it works fine but edit doesn't